# how can i get news from jQuery datepicker calendar?

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I made datepicker code, absolutely similar to http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline
and i want to make news calendar:

*JS side:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
           window.open("?action=news_archive&date=" + dateText + "&lang=<?=$lang?>"); 
        }
     }
);

});
```

*PHP side:*

```
$date = $_GET[ "date" ];
mysql_query(SELECT * FROM news WHERE date = $date);
```

but when i refresh page, i'm able to link all pages what i pressed, and if there is similarity, it retrieves news, if not the page is empty. i want to filter and make url only if there is a record and this record is similar to my date in mysql database.

the url's i have:

> index.php?action=news_archive&date=2011-07-07&lang=eng
>
> index.php?action=news_archive&date=2011-07-08&lang=eng
>
> index.php?action=news_archive&date=2011-07-09&lang=eng

and so on...

but i don't have news linked on **2011-07-08** and **2011-07-09** in my mysql database, so i don't want to be linked 08 and 09 on my calendar.

sorry for my bed english and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to bring a list of the dates from the db where there are news, and use that list to disable the calendar dates using the [`beforeShowDay`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) event of the datepicker..

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date) {
     // check if date is in the list and if so return [true]
     // or [false] if the date is not active..
   },
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
       window.open("?action=news_archive&date=" + dateText + "&lang=<?=$lang?>"); 
   }
});
```

Comment: so i don't need that code?

**$("#datepicker").datepicker({
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
           window.open("?action=news_archive&date=" + dateText + "&lang=<?=$lang?>"); 
        }
     }**

and change it to

*
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay: function(date) {
     // check if date is in the list and if so return [true]
     // or [false] if the date is not active..
   }
}); 
*

Comment: @user832399, wait. The example i gave is to be added as additional to your existing code. My code will just disable the buttons in the datepicker. You still need your code in order to open the page with the actual news.. *updating answer to show how to use both events*)